# minimize all windows by pressing windows with d in ubuntu like windows

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

How can i minimize my all open windows by pressing <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in Ubuntu? I can do this in windows easily but with Ubuntu i do not know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut to minimize all windows is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and show the desktop. The <kbd>super</kbd> is the 'windows' key you are talking about.

You can change the shortcut in

**Dash > System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows**